# Why are my BackgroundService Args always null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, arguments, windows-services, background-service

I am using a BackgroundService in .Net Core 3.1.

There are two Sections of code, The first is the BackgroundService itself which I am using in its published format. Using the same methods from the following guide: https://youtu.be/PzrTiz_NRKA?t=2050

The Second Project is a Service Controller which I am trying to use to Start the Service and pass arguments to it.

The Main BackgroundService Application:

```
   public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(@"C:\temp\workerservice\logfile.txt")
            .CreateLogger();

        Log.Information($"Test Args Given {args}");

        var param = Console.ReadLine();
        Log.Information($"Params {string.Join("", args)}");

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting The Service");
            Log.Information($"Args Given {string.Join("", args)}");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Problem Starting the Service");
            return;
        }
        finally {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                DriverConfig options = configuration.GetSection("DriverConfig").Get<DriverConfig>();
                Log.Information($"Running with options {options.DriverName} at {options.IpAddress}");
                services.AddSingleton(options);
                services.AddSingleton<CustomDriver, ExampleDriver>();
                services.AddHostedService<DriverSetup>();
            }).UseSerilog();
}
```

The Second Code Snippet is the Service Controller which is being run in a Console App (As Administrator):

The Service Was published with the Name "MQTTArgless", it is picked up and the service is started correctly. The Arguments appear to be parsed as well. So the problem does not appear to be in this section of code.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceController[] objService;
        objService = ServiceController.GetServices();
        string[] Driver1Config = new string[] { "DriverTemplate", "http://localhost:5001"};

        foreach (ServiceController SController in objService)
        {
            if (SController.ServiceName == "MQTTArgless")
            {
                ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MQTTArgless", "MSI");
                Console.WriteLine("Status = " + sc.Status);
                Console.WriteLine("Can Pause and Continue = " + sc.CanPauseAndContinue);
                Console.WriteLine("Can ShutDown = " + sc.CanShutdown);
                Console.WriteLine("Can Stop = " + sc.CanStop);
                string[] argArray = new string[] { "MQTTArgless", "http://MSI:5001" };
                sc.Start(argArray);
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            }

        }
    }
```

The Issue is that from the Worker Service I cannot see any arguments as args comes in as null.
Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you pass parameters through the command line: (net start MQTTArgless /a )?

Comment: Sadly not, I use Log.Information($"args {string.Join("", args)}"); to check what they come out as, and nothing is logged